# sort table by each column in a table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working in MVC4, using c# and jquery my task is to sort table by clicking on column header i have used some jquery method's that sort perfectly text and numbers but it does't sort table by date wise i have tried with different date's(2/12/2014,12/15/2010,3/10/2014,14/05/2014)

my jquery code is:

```js
$Sorting = function ($ele) {
    var table = $ele.parents('table').eq(0);
    var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($ele.index()));
    this.asc = !this.asc;
    if (!(this.asc)) { rows = rows.reverse(); }
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { table.append(rows[i]); }
}
function comparer(index) {
    return function (a, b) {
        var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index);
        return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB);
    }
}
function getCellValue(row, index) { return $(row).children('td').eq(index).html() }
```

please help me how to sort table with date,text and integer values

Comment: edited text and corrected syntax highlightning

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're sorting on text-based values, while you'd want to be interpreting those values on their numeric contents.

In the past, I made a hidden field in the date column (each row) with the date written out as YYYYMMDD (e.g. today is 20150311).

```
<td>
    <span class="invisibleSpan">20150311</span>
    11/03/2015
<td>
```

If you sort on that hidden value, both sorting as text and as numerical value will work identically, which should simplify your basic sorting algorithm since you don't have to parse the date string anymore.

**Edit** Make sure to add a leading 0 for one-digit months and days. Otherwise, the sorting won't work as expected.

On the other hand, there are a lot of JS/jQuery libraries that already implement better solutions.
I've always had good experiences with [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/), although I have to admit it might be overkill if you're *only* looking for a sorting option. DataTables carries a lot of features and does get a bit intrusive with its CSS and table handling.